# merging cells in column based on condition

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I am trying to merge the cells in a column (column B) based on a condition in another column (Column C).

In Column C, I have a list that starts at 1 and goes to a maximum of 10. However, it may stop at any number before 10 and restart. For Example:

```
B C

  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  1
  2
  3
  4
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  1
```

As you can see, at B7 and B11, Column C starts over a 1. When this happens, I would like to merge everything above that restart (from 1 to last number before restart). So for this example, I would like to merge B1:B6, B7:10, and B11:15.

Answer (score 1):

This short loop using the [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to locate 'ones' should suffice.

```
Dim srw As Long, frw As Variant
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With Intersect(.Columns(3), .UsedRange)
        srw = 0
        Do While srw < .Rows.Count
            frw = Application.Match(1, .Columns(1).Offset(srw + 1, 0), 0)
            If Not IsError(frw) Then
                .Cells(srw + 1, 1).Resize(frw, 1).Offset(0, -1).Merge
                srw = srw + frw
            Else
                srw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End With
```

It's just a matter of finding the restarting point (the 'ones') and using a little maths to resize the cells to be merged.

---

[image: merge_groups]

Comment: Awesome, I see it working. However, I have cells above the table that I do not want merged. So, the table really starts at Cells B9&C9. Is there something I can add or edit in the code to make the code only apply to cells C9:B169? I am very new to VBA code, not to familiar with it.

Comment: You might try `srw = 8`.

Comment: Perfect. Worked. Now I have a few follow up questions.

1) I placed a button and assigned this code to it so it runs once you press the button and I get a Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (400) error when I press the button. Any suggestions?

2) When I'm typing the list, I won't always end it with "1" so everything above will merge. For example: in your table, if you removed the "1" from C16, so it was just 1 to 5 from C11:C16, can I add something to the code to know to merge that?

3) Lastly, do you have a VBA code to add a thicker border to all cells above the "1" from Column B to O?.

Comment: If you have follow-up questions then close this question off and post follow-up questions with the updated information; referring back to this question if you think it will provide relevant information. Otherwise, this become a [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625). btw, people asking for code are ***expected** to show oriinal effort; I answered this because I found it interesting but so far you've shown no original effort.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative code pattern, using a formula approach with a helper column (cleared before ending) by which jumping through relevant rows only

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim i As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet001")
    With .Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        With .Offset(, 1)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(RC[-1]=1,"""",1)"
            .Value = .Value
            With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
                For i = 1 To .Areas.Count - 1
                    Range(.Areas(i).Cells(.Areas(i).Count), .Areas(i + 1).Cells(1).Offset(-1)).Offset(0, -2).Merge
                Next i
            End With
            .ClearContents
        End With
    End With
End With

End Sub
```